# Django: python manage.py runserver is not working

Tags: python, django

[Out: Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlUJd.jpg)

I'm having a problem with Django, like in the picture, when I try to start the server or make a migration, I just get the output: "python" back.
I'm using Windows 10 and Python 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you successfully installed python by typing `python3` in the cmd. You should see a version number and an interactive session opens. Exit it with `exit()`. Then try with `python3 manage.py`.

Comment: Thank you for the fast Answer, python 3.8 is installed, i tried with the command python3 running the server, but i get the same result "Python".